# saxon.FeatureKeys importing error in java spring-boot project

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I am getting the saxon-importing error like,

```
The "import net.sf.saxon.FeatureKeys" cannot be resolved.
```

How can I add the dependency to resolve the "net.sf.saxon.FeatureKeys" error.

I have already added the given dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE -->
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
<artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
<version>10.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `import net.sf.saxon.lib.FeatureKeys`, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/FeatureKeys.html

Comment: Thanks Martin, the import error is resolved now.

Comment: @Kakashi, consider to accept this answer as the import problem is solved. For the other problem, raise a new question with minimal but complete details to understand and reproduce it.

Comment: Sure @Martin Honnen , I have posted a new question. Can you please look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896687/i-am-getting-exception-in-xslt-saxon-parser