# I am getting exception in XSLT saxon parser

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I have added a maven dependency for saxen parser, then sending the xml and xsl as a string parameter to the saxonTransform(String xml, String xsl). But getting some exception.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE -->
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
<artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
<version>10.6</version>
</dependency>
```

SAXON TRANSFORMER(XSLT) CODE:

```
public static String saxonTransform(String xml, String xsl) throws TransformerException, FileNotFoundException {

String result = "";

System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory", "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");

System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");

StringWriter out = new StringWriter();

TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

tFactory.setAttribute(FeatureKeys.DTD_VALIDATION, false);

StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));

StreamSource xslSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl));

StreamResult xmlResult = new StreamResult(out);

Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);

transformer.transform(xmlSource, xmlResult);

result = out.toString();

return result;

}
```

But, the given line is not able to transform the xml:

```
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
```

Giving the error like:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
[Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError:
Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found] with root cause
```

Comment: Why do you need `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl`? Can't you use the default SAX parser of the JRE/JDK? If you need Xerces, have you added it also as a dependency?

Comment: We need org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl  Because the SAX parser(of jdk,jre ) was not working with our xsl-stylesheet. Then I added the  maven dependency for Saxon-Parsor.

Comment: If the JDK parser "wasn't working" then it might be better to work out what the problem was, rather than trying a different parser. What was the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory",
    "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");
```

you're saying that you want to use Apache Xerces as your XML parser, but it looks is if it's not available on the classpath.

(Note that for most purposes these days, using the version of Xerces that's built into the JDK works perfectly well. There was a time when the JDK version had some nasty bugs, but that seems to have been fixed a while ago.)

Comment: Hi Michael, Then how I add this property in class path?

Comment: It depends on the environment you're working in. There's a mention in the stack trace of Servlets, which suggests some kind of application server. They all have different ways of setting the classpath (and I'm not very familiar with any of them). But since you added a Maven dependency for Saxon, perhaps you should add one for Apache Xerces as well.